# Show that $R[x]/J[x]\cong (R/J)[x]$, where $J$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> If $J$ is an ideal of the ring $R$, show that $J[x]$ is an ideal in $R[x]$ and show that $R[x]/J[x]\cong (R/J)[x]$.
>   *Hint:* Find a natural homomorphism from $R[x]$ onto $(R/J)[x]$ with kernel $J[x]$.

I think I can do the first part using the correspondence theorem.

For the second part, I'm certain we're going to need to use the/a homomorphism theorem. I thought of a few possible functions. One function was $\varphi: R[x]\to (R/J)[x]$ by $p\mapsto p-q$ where the coefficients of $q$ are in $R/J$. But after trying to show that $\ker \varphi = J[x]$, I realized that this might not be a homomorphism.

Another one was $\psi$, where $p\mapsto cp$, where $c\in R/J$. I sketched it out, and I believe $\psi$ is actually a homomorphism.

I think it's true that $\ker\psi\subseteq J[x]$. In the other direction, if $p\in J[x]$, then $\psi(p) = cp\in J[x]$. But that's where I got stuck. I don't think this shows equality. Regardless, I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track, and I've run out of potential homomorphisms. I was hoping for some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think either of those maps you defined are functions into $(R/J)[X]$.  The elements of $(R/J)[X]$ should be polynomials whose coefficients are cosets $r + J$, where $r \in R$.

Comment: If you show the quotients are isomorphic this also shows J[x] is an ideal.

Comment: I think your map should be the innocent map r+(a bunch of crap) _______> r+(stupid shit) and then show you have the same minimal set of r's necessary.

Comment: Minimal set of $r$s?  What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Define a homomorphism $\phi:R[X] \rightarrow R/J[X]$ by the formula $$\phi(a_0 +a_1X + \cdots + a_n X^n) = (a_0 + J) + (a_1 +J)X + \cdots + (a_n + J)X^n$$ Once you check that it is a homomorphism (it sends the identity to the identity, and distributes over addition and multiplication), it is immediate that it is surjective.

Injectivity follows from the fact that a polynomial is zero if and only if all its coefficients are zero.  To say that $f(X) =a_0 + \cdots + a_nX^n$ gets mapped to zero is the same thing as saying that all the entries $a_i + J$ are the zero element in $R/J$.  And $a_i + J$ is the zero element in $R/J$ if and only if $a_i$ is an element of $J$.  Thus $f(X)$ is mapped to zero if and only if all its entries lie in $J$, i.e. $f(X) \in J[X]$.

So $J[X]$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi$.  This implies that $J[X]$ is an ideal; an ideal of a ring is the same thing as the kernel of a homomorphism.

Comment: I did think of something like this, but I thought it was strange write the coefficients as $(a_i+J)$ as you have done. Is this abuse of notation? Or is there a nicer way (per se) to say that $\phi$ sends the coefficients to $a_i+J$. Actually, this is similar to the idea with my $\varphi$. So can I instead say that $\phi$ maps by $p\mapsto p+q$, where the coefficients of $q$ are in $R/J$. That's what I want right? Since, $J$ is an ideal of $R$, the $a+J$ are the cosets which form $R/J$. Sorry, I'm still straightening this all out.

Comment: There was no real abuse of notation in my post.  The elements of $R/J$ are literally sets of the form $r +J$, where $r+J$ is by definition $$ \{ r + x : x \in J \}$$ If $S$ is any ring, $S[X]$ is the set of formal sums of the form $s_0 + s_1X + s_2X^2 + \cdots + s_nX^n$, where $n \geq 1$ and $s_i$ are elements of $S$.  So the elements of $R/J[X]$ are the way I've written them.

Comment: As you've written it, $p+q$ does not make sense without further elaboration; and you would have to say what $q$ is, specifically.  If you don't like the way things look in my answer, you might prefer Tsemo Aristide's: let $\pi: R \rightarrow R/J$ be the homomorphism given by $\pi(r) = r + J$.  Then $$(a_0 + J) + (a_1 + J)X + \cdots + (a_n + J)X^n$$ is exactly the same element of $R/J[X]$ as $$\pi(a_0) + \pi(a_1) X + \cdots + \pi(a_n)X^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $p:R\rightarrow R/J$ be the quotient map, consider $f:R[x]\rightarrow (R/J)(x)$ defined by $f(a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n)=p(a_0)+p(a_1)x+..+p(a_n)x^n$, $f$ is a morphism of rings which is surjective: Let $\sum_ib_ix^i\in R/J[x]$, there exists $a_i\in R$ such that $p(a_i)=b_i$, thus $f(\sum a_ix^i)=\sum_ib_ix^i$. $f$ is also injective since $p(a_0)+p(a_1)x+..+p(a_n)x^n=0$ implies that $p(a_i)=0, i=1,..,n$ which is equivalent to say that $a_0+a_1x+..+a_nx^n\in J[x]$ thus the kernel of $f$ is $J[x]$.